# c++: оптимизация вызова небольших функций

Tags: c++, функции, оптимизация, inline

подскажите пожалуйста по такому вопросу:

есть короткие (зачастую) однострочные функции типа

```
bool is_intersect(const int a, const int b)
{
    return ((a & b) != 0);
}
```

которые участвуют в ресурсоемких расчетах и судя по отладчику на такие вызовы приходится значительное время

можно ли их как-то оптимизировать на уровне кода типа

```
inline bool is_intersect(const int a, const int b)
{
    return ((a & b) != 0);
}
```

или компилятор и так умный и не будет делать вызов функций, а встроит их начинку в основной код убрав вызовы и т.д.?

Comment: Странный вопрос, конечно лучше `inline` писать таким функциям, а не надеяться, что компилятор сам сделает это. Можно еще почитать про соглашение о вызовах ([__fastcall](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=msvc-160) или [__cdecl](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-160)) но они мне кажется больше для библиотечных функций.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков наличие или отсуствие inline на встраивание функции уже давно не влияет

Comment: @user7860670 `override` тоже, но лично я и то, и другое пишу.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Писать и то, и другое, чтобы функция встраивалась не имеет смысла.

Comment: @user7860670 я повторюсь `override` тоже можно не писать (я не говорю, что не имеет смысла конечно, но можно не писать) для меня лично с `inline` так же.

Comment: override лучше писать - защищает от очень неприятных багов

Comment: @KoVadim специально чтобы такой комментарий никто не написал я добавил в скобочках информацию :)

Comment: Вы плохо добавили "информацию".

Answer (score 5):

Современные компиляторы достаточно умные чтобы встраивать вызовы небольших функций. Главное - не забудьте разрешить оптимизацию. К слову, та же студия по умолчанию в отладочной сборке оптимизацию выключает - так что время замерять надо не отладчиком, а профайлером.

А вот модификатор `inline`, как ни странно, на встраивание функций не влияет! Единственное его назначение - разрешить нахождение функции в заголовочном файле.

Comment: это я не то написал, конечно профайлером в Release с Ox оптимизацией и прочим

Answer (score 2):

Компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные и если их попросить, то могут такое так оптимизировать, что пользователь никогда бы не догадался. Главное ему не мешать.

В Вашем случае const - это обычное излишество. Для типа int, который передается по значению, оно не имеет смысла (по ссылке/указателю также нет смысла передавать).

Но вот если сигнатура функции будет где то такая `void foo(int* a, int* b)` - тут компилятор может решить, что эти "массивы" (да, я  специально в кавычках написал) могут пересекаться и сгенерирует далеко не самый оптимальный код.

В данный момент inline - это просто подсказка компилятору, а не призыв к действию. В некоторых случаях (например, clang) компилятор может даже поступить наоборот, если видит много inline. Но если очень сильно-сильно хочется, то компилятор можно попросить сделать это "насильственно". Например, для visual studio это `__forceinline`. Но в любом случае нужно делать бенчмарки и смотреть.

В многих случаях получить ускорение можно за счет изменения алгоритма. К примеру, не использовать сортировку пузырьком, если только на то нет ну особо важных причин.

Если же Вы гадаете, делать инлайн или нет, скорее всего либо Вы уже уперлись в предел, либо копаете совсем не в том направлении.

Comment: Вот `const` тут как раз на своем месте - `a` и `b` же внутри функции не меняются.

Comment: смысла в них никакого.

Comment: Смысл в том, что соблюдается const correctness.

Comment: я знаю, что некоторые люди буквально помешаны на ней. И иногда она бывает полезной. Но вот в этом конкретном случае она совсем ничего не дает. Ну кроме галочки для себя "у меня все константно корректно".

Comment: именно уперся, алгоритм принципиально не изменить уже, он и так оптимален - разве что всякие SSE притягивать и то не факт, что компилятор это не делает, из последнего - использование `__popcnt` помогло (компилятор не понял, что код подсчитывает биты, так что пришлось такие вещи использовать) :) А касательно приведенного примера в вопросе - было бы вообще идеально если бы без `if` можно было бы как-то получать `0` или `1` в зависимости  от того выполняется условие или нет -  ибо условия жрут очень много временных ресурсов :(

Comment: А const correctness не получится "использовать иногда". Она либо соблюдается в коде, либо нет.

Comment: @Zhihar тогда может лучше смотреть на код "чуть выше". SSE, если правильно применить, может ускорить до 2--3 раз участок кода. Но закон Амадала никто не отменял

Comment: @Zhihar "если бы без if можно было бы как-то получать 0 или 1" - ну так это совсем просто - `int x = (int)(a > b);` (любители красоты могут добавить static_cast и другого). Но компилятор скорее всего сам это сможет

Comment: @KoVadim, `a > b` это и есть `if` со всеми вытекающими, например узнать, что в массиве есть ненулевой элемент (при не очень большом размере массива) выгоднее по скорости через `res |= arr[i]... return res != 0` чем через `if (arr[i] == 0) return false` - потому что процессор не очень любит гоутушить :)

Comment: у процессоров давно есть инструкция sete к примеру, которая как раз может убрать if. Но вот sse могут и помочь в этом деле. Почитайте это https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141201-00/?p=43503

Comment: А если это: `return ((a & b) != 0)` заменить на это: `return (bool)(a & b) ` ? Вроде, результат будет тот-же самый, но без проверки на неравенство.... Или я не прав?

Comment: скорее всего компилятор в обох случаях сделает одинаковый код. Но вот только в первом случае код выглядит красиво и очевидно. А вот взяв второй способ, можно увлечься и получить [bool который и не true и не false](https://habr.com/ru/post/338898/)